# Protecting the SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, code-signing

In my app I have a database which must be protected with a key to restrict other apps on this device from accessing it.

The problem is that I cannot get the signing key in runtime: whatever I do the `CodeSigningKey.get(...)` always returns `null`.

This is my code:

```
    final CodeSigningKey key = CodeSigningKey.get(AbstractDB.class);
    if (key != null) {
        Log.d("+ GOT SIGNING KEY");
        final DatabaseSecurityOptions secopt = new DatabaseSecurityOptions(key);
        db = DatabaseFactory.create(name,  secopt);
    } else {
        Log.d("- SIGNING KEY IS NULL");
    }
```

I have downloaded Signing Authority Tool and created a `TEST.key` using it, and put it in `{project_root}/keys/TEST.key` in my Eclipse project.

Also, I've doule-clicked `TEST.key` in Eclipse and selected `AbstractDB` class to be signed with it.

**I run my app on a real device, not in the simulator.**

I run it as follows:

1. start debugging on a device - this initiates packaging and siging the .cod file. *(However, in the signing tool window I get a warning about my TEST.key: "Not registered" and "Please contact the signer and register with the Signing Authority.")*
2. with Signing Authority Tool I sign my .cod file obtained on step 1 using my `TEST.key`
3. I click debug on device once again, and the signing tool signs the main .cod file again, and then the app starts on the device.

However, the key I get from `CodeSigningKey.get(..)` is always `null`.

What do I do wrong?

### Solution

After a hint from Michael I was able to resolve this problem.

First of all, indeed I needed an object instance in `CodeSigningKey.get(...)`. However, there is one thing you should aware of: if your object extends some classes and/or implements some interfaces, then ALL of those must be signed with same key in order to work. If any of ancestor classes/interfaces is not signed you will get `null`.

This can be a problem if your hierarchy is deep enough. Information about which classes are signed with which keys is stored in `BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml`, and copied into parameters of signing tool when you click Debug. It may happen that command line gets too long so the signing tool fails with "Invalid parameter" message in the console.

So I've extracted a class specially for the signing purpose:

```
final public class SignatureClass {
    private static final SignatureClass INSTANCE = new SignatureClass();

    private SignatureClass() { }

    public static CodeSigningKey getKey() {
        return CodeSigningKey.get(INSTANCE);
    }
}
```

I sign only this class with my key and use `SignatureClass.getKey()` to get the key.

*PS: Also, if you move/rename classes or keys check that signing references in the `BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml` are valid. They aren't updated automatically.*

### Update

How to issue your own signing key properly.

In the process I've described above I had to sign the .cod file with a separate tool because the built-in signing tool gave error "Not registered" for my `TEST.key`. In order to fix this and have your .cod signed automatically in one go, do following steps.

1. After you have created your key with Signing Authority Tool, launch the WebAdmin utility included in that app. It offers you to create the keys database and launch the WebSigner service.
2. Having successfully started the WebAdmin, click menu `Record->Add`. You'll get a window where you can create a .csi file. Configure: number of requests - infinite; expiry date - never; email notifications - none; email CSI file - no. Click OK and you'll see a dialog with a generated PIN - save it for future use. The .csi file is generated and saved in /data folder in Signing Authority Tool.
3. Install the .csi file using `Eclipse->Window->Preferences->BlackBerry plugin->Signature Tool->Install new keys` and register it using the PIN from step 2.

Done. From now on, when signing with RIM keys you'll have your .cod automatically signed also with your key.

Comment: `There is no way to create a non-encrypted database and restrict its usage to only one application. This is because there are other ways (using file I/O operations) to read a plain-text database file from any application.`  http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/database/DatabaseSecurityOptions.html

Comment: I did not follow how you got the code signing key. http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/CodeSigningKey.html  It's as simple as creating a single-purpose class that acts as the signature? Are you doing this now: `final DatabaseSecurityOptions secopt = new DatabaseSecurityOptions(SignatureClass.getKey())` ?

Comment: @Tim I've added an update to my original post.

Comment: you should consider putting the solution in as an answer below and not in the question. Nice details soln.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need an object instance from your app, instead of a class object.  In this case 'this' ought to work.

Comment: Thanks for help, Michael! I've added solution to my original post.